# What is the energy difference between the 3d 4s valence subshells of iron (and copper)?

Tags: visible-light, electrons, atomic-physics, atoms, absorption

In gold, for example, the energy difference between the 5d 6s valence subshells is ≈ 2.7 eV (that's why it has color). But what about the 3d 4s subshells of iron and copper? What are their energy differences? My interest is more about the iron.